# Rotate imageData in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Okay I think I have to make this more clear :)

My code is working for square images, but it is doing nothing with rectangular images.
I think it's because imageData.width and imageData.height are still the same and can't be changed.

Do you guys know how I could get that working?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas0calc");
var ctx  = canvas.getContext('2d');

var objImageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

// swap canvas size
var temp = canvas.width;
canvas.width = canvas.height;
canvas.height = temp;


//create new Array for Data
var newImageData = new Array(objImageData.height);
for (var k = 0; k < newImageData.length; k++) {
    newImageData[k] = new Array(objImageData.width);
}

//the actual matrix-rotate algorithm which is working perfectly
for (var i = 0; i < objImageData.height; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < objImageData.width; j++) {
        newImageData[i][j] = [objImageData.data[((i*(objImageData.width*4)) + ((objImageData.width - j - 1)*4))], objImageData.data[((i*(objImageData.width*4)) + ((objImageData.width - j - 1)*4)) + 1],objImageData.data[((i*(objImageData.width*4)) + ((objImageData.width - j - 1)*4)) + 2],objImageData.data[((i*(objImageData.width*4)) + ((objImageData.width - j - 1)*4)) + 3]];
    }
}

var resultArray = new Array(objImageData.width * objImageData.height * 4);
var count = 0;
for (var y = 0; y < newImageData.length; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < newImageData[0].length; x++) {
        for (var z = 0; z < 4; z++) {
            resultArray[count++] = newImageData[x][y][z];
        }
    }
}

for (var u = 0; u < objImageData.data.length; u++) {
    objImageData.data[u] = resultArray[u];
}

ctx.putImageData(objImageData, 0, 0);
```

Comment: can you show us the implementation of your rotation algorithm?

Comment: I updated the question, I think it should be more clear now :D

Answer (score 3):

There's more to it than just swapping the width and height values! If I take a square then rotate it by 45°, Then swapping the width and height will do nothing - the image is actually sqrt(2) times as wide and high as it was previously (the length from one diagonal corner to another is sqrt( 1^2 + 1^2) times the length between adjacent corners. The point is, you need to calculate your new image dimensions a little better than a simple swap.

I can't seem to find image rotation routines on the net anywhere near as easily as I could 10 or 15 years ago - it's all the fast graphics hardware we have now that's made it redundant for a lot of people's needs.

It's unclear if you'd like to rotate by 90°, 180° or 270° - I suspect so by the simple swapping of width and height, though I can't be certain. If so, see this article here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21446/Fast-Image-Rotation-For-NET-Compact-Framework

If however, you'd like to rotate by an arbitrary angle, read on.

I realize it's C and you're using javascript - but in any case, the rotation maths is just the same, just ignore/use equiv javascript functions as required.

```
// RotateMemoryDC rotates a memory DC and returns the rotated DC as well as its dimensions
HBITMAP RotateMemoryDC(HBITMAP hBmpSrc, float angleDeg)
{
    HBITMAP hBmpDst;
    float x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y3, y4, cA, sA;
    float CtX, CtY, orgX, orgY, divisor;
    int OfX, OfY;
    int stepX, stepY;
    int iorgX, iorgY;
    RECT rt;
    pBGR src, dst, dstLine;
    BITMAPINFO bi;
    // my edits
    BITMAP bm;
    int SrcX, SrcY, dstX, dstY;     // were input variables, with the & symbol in front of them (input/output vars)\

    HDC hdcSrc, hdcDst, hdcScreen;

    HBITMAP oldDstBmp, oldSrcBmp;

    GetObject(hBmpSrc, sizeof(bm), &bm);
    SrcX = bm.bmWidth;
    SrcY = bm.bmHeight;

    // Rotate the bitmap around the center
    CtX = ((float) SrcX) / 2;
    CtY = ((float) SrcY) / 2;

    // First, calculate the destination positions for the four courners to get dstX and dstY
    float angleRad = angleDeg * 3.1415926 / 180.0;
    cA = (float) cos(angleRad);
    sA = (float) sin(angleRad);

    x1 = CtX + (-CtX) * cA - (-CtY) * sA;
    x2 = CtX + (SrcX - CtX) * cA - (-CtY) * sA;
    x3 = CtX + (SrcX - CtX) * cA - (SrcY - CtY) * sA;
    x4 = CtX + (-CtX) * cA - (SrcY - CtY) * sA;

    y1 = CtY + (-CtY) * cA + (-CtX) * sA;
    y2 = CtY + (SrcY - CtY) * cA + (-CtX) * sA;
    y3 = CtY + (SrcY - CtY) * cA + (SrcX - CtX) * sA;
    y4 = CtY + (-CtY) * cA + (SrcX - CtX) * sA;

    OfX = ((int) floor(min4(x1, x2, x3, x4)));
    OfY = ((int) floor(min4(y1, y2, y3, y4)));

    dstX = ((int) ceil(max4(x1, x2, x3, x4))) - OfX;
    dstY = ((int) ceil(max4(y1, y2, y3, y4))) - OfY;

    // Create the new memory DC
    hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
    hdcDst = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);
    hdcSrc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);
    hBmpDst = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, dstX, dstY);
    oldDstBmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcDst, hBmpDst);
    oldSrcBmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcSrc, hBmpSrc);

    // Fill the new memory DC with the current Window color
    rt.left = 0;
    rt.top = 0;
    rt.right = dstX;
    rt.bottom = dstY;
    HBRUSH redBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,0,0));

    FillRect(hdcDst, &rt, redBrush);
    DeleteObject(redBrush);

    // Get the bitmap bits for the source and destination
    src = MyGetDibBits(hdcSrc, hBmpSrc, SrcX, SrcY);
    dst = MyGetDibBits(hdcDst, hBmpDst, dstX, dstY);

    dstLine = dst;
    divisor = cA*cA + sA*sA;
    // Step through the destination bitmap
    for (stepY = 0; stepY < dstY; stepY++)
    {
        for (stepX = 0; stepX < dstX; stepX++)
        {
            // Calculate the source coordinate
            orgX = (cA * (((float) stepX + OfX) + CtX * (cA - 1)) + sA * (((float) stepY + OfY) + CtY * (sA - 1))) / divisor;
            orgY = CtY + (CtX - ((float) stepX + OfX)) * sA + cA *(((float) stepY + OfY) - CtY + (CtY - CtX) * sA);
            iorgX = (int) orgX;
            iorgY = (int) orgY;
            if ((iorgX >= 0) && (iorgY >= 0) && (iorgX < SrcX) && (iorgY < SrcY))
            {
                // Inside the source bitmap -> copy the bits
                dstLine[dstX - stepX - 1] = src[iorgX + iorgY * SrcX];
            }
            else
            {
                // Outside the source -> set the color to light grey
                //  dstLine[dstX - stepX - 1].b = 240;
                //  dstLine[dstX - stepX - 1].g = 20;
                //  dstLine[dstX - stepX - 1].r = 240;
            }
        }
        dstLine = dstLine + dstX;
    }

    // Set the new Bitmap
    bi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bi.bmiHeader);
    bi.bmiHeader.biWidth = dstX;
    bi.bmiHeader.biHeight = dstY;
    bi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    bi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = dstX * 4 * dstY;
    bi.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
    bi.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
    SetDIBits(hdcDst, hBmpDst, 0, dstY, dst, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    // Free the color arrays
    free(src);
    free(dst);
    SelectObject(hdcSrc, oldSrcBmp);
    SelectObject(hdcDst, oldDstBmp);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcScreen);
    DeleteDC(hdcSrc);
    DeleteDC(hdcDst);
    return hBmpDst;
}
```